# Spring application inside of dotCMS

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, content-management-system, dotcms

Please tell me what's the best way to get a Spring MVC application working inside of dotCMS. I've already tried creating dynamc OSGI plugins, but they don't seem to support jsp technology (controller is able to give you only an html page, not jsp).

Answer (score 0):

Not all spring features are supported by dotCMS out of the box. What is supported can be read on their documentation page about dynamic plugins which can be found here: http://dotcms.com/docs/latest/DevelopingANewDynamicPlugin

Answer (score 0):

dotCMS uses Velocity as the "View" in the MVC.  You need to map your view logic to a page in the dotCMS as described here:

http://dotcms.com/blog/post/spring-mvc-support-in-dotcms-2-0